# how to get random 1/2 data from database in jinj2 template in Django?

Tags: django, jinja2

```
<table>
{% for field in fields %}
<tr>
<td>{{ field.name }}</td>
<td>{{ field.value }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

here we will get all the data from fields . but i want to  only get randomly 1/2 (i can specified how many) data in jinja2 template from backend ?
How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
{% for field in fields %}

   {% if forloop.counter < x %}
   <tr>
    <td>{{ field.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ field.value }}</td>
   </tr>
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</table>
```

just put your desired number in x,you are good to go.

Comment: if you want just random,you have to explicitly use some tags written in python.i think you want that?

Comment: yeah . If i can do this, that would be awesome . Do you have solution on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can add this logic to the frontend. This way it will display records with even ID. and those will 1/2 as well.

```
<table>
{% for field in fields %}
<tr>
{% if field.id%2 == 0 %}
<td>{{ field.name }}</td>
<td>{{ field.value }}</td>
{% endif %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```